# What is wrong with this database query?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have the following tables in a database (i'll only list the important attributes):

```
Person(ssn,countryofbirth)
Parents(ssn,fatherbirthcountry)
Employment(ssn, companyID)
Company(companyID, name)
```

My task is this: given fatherbirthcountry as input, output the names of companies where persons work whose countryofbirth match the fatherbirthcountry input.

I pretend that the fatherbirthcountry is Mexico and do this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Company 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT companyid  
                   FROM Employment 
                   WHERE ssn = (SELECT ssn 
                                FROM Person 
                                WHERE countryofbirth = 'Mexico');
```

but it is giving me an error:

```
>Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row.
```

am I completely off track?  Can anybody please help?

Comment: When i was typing my answer, i got a message "6 New answers have been posted. Load new answers?" (within 2 minutes)...

Comment: Whatever approach you go with, you'll likely want to `SELECT DISTINCT name...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your subqueries are returning multiple results, so you have to use `where in` vs. `=`.

Change `where ssn =` to `where ssn in`, and `where companyid =` to `where companyid in`.

Answer (score 2):

try using the IN keyword not '='.

try changing your query to this

SELECT name 
FROM Company 
WHERE companyid IN (SELECT companyid
                   FROM Employment 
                   WHERE ssn IN (SELECT ssn 
                                FROM Person 
                                WHERE countryofbirth = 'Mexico');

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT c.name
  FROM COMPANY c
  JOIN EMPLOYMENT e ON e.companyid = c.companyid
  JOIN PERSON p ON p.ssn = e.ssn
               AND p.countryofbirth = 'Mexico'
```

Comment: actually, the sub queries and the joins use the same query plans on SQL Server.  Try it out.

Comment: it may not perform better, but imho it's a hellofalot easier to read

Comment: @David B: I'll test tomorrow, but the question appears to relate to Derby - no SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `In` in the `where` condition since the `(SELECT ssn 
                                FROM Person 
                                WHERE countryofbirth = 'Mexico');` may return multiple ssn values.

```
SELECT name 
FROM Company 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT companyid  
                   FROM Employment 
                   WHERE ssn IN (SELECT ssn 
                                FROM Person 
                                WHERE countryofbirth = 'Mexico');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IN` instead of `=`

When you write:

```
select a from T where a = ( select....)
```

The sub-query must return a single value. In case if it returns multiple values, you get your error.

To solve this we use the IN operator which allows the sub-query to return a set of value (>=0) and your where condition succeeds if `a` equals any one of those values.

```
select a from T where a IN ( select....)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

> SELECT    c.Name    FROM PERSON p
>   LEFT JOIN Employment e ON p.ssn=e.ssn 
>   LEFT JOIN Company c ON
>   e.CompanyID=c.CompanyID    WHERE
>   p.countryofbirth=

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the one of the two subqueries are returning multiple rows. I would think it likely that you have multiple people born in Mexico for example.

```
Select Name
From  Companies
Where Exists(
            Select 1
            From Employment
                Join Person
                    On Person.SSN = Employment.SSN
                Join Parents
                    On Parents.SSN = Person.SSN
            Where Parents.FatherBirthCountry = Person.CountryOfBirth
                And Parents.FatherBirthCountry = @InputParam
                And Employment.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally use the answer from [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430629/what-is-wrong-with-this-database-query/2430675#2430675) using `JOIN`s.
But if you do not like `JOIN`s for whatever reason, then `TOP 1` should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT  name 
FROM    Company 
WHERE   companyid =(SELECT  TOP 1 companyid  
                    FROM    Employment 
                    WHERE   ssn = ( SELECT  TOP 1 ssn 
                                    FROM    Person 
                                    WHERE   countryofbirth = 'Mexico');
```